# ¿Cómo conseguir la extensión de un archivo en CMD, Batch?

Tags: cmd, batch

Quiero renombrar unos archivos. Basicamente es solo cambiar el orden de las palabras del propio nombre de los archivos. Para ese fin me he hecho un programa en C++ y quiero ejecutarlo desde un BAT. Necesito la extension de los archivos para pasarselo como parametro a mi EXE (**"%EXTENSION%"**). Porque tengo varrios archivos con el mismo nombre y diferente extensión. ¿cómo puedo conseguir las extensiones? Este es mi código:

```
set CurrDir=%cd%
set BatchFileDir=%~dp0

REM UTF-8
chcp 65001

goto :main

:GetFileData
for /R %CurrDir% %%i in (*.*) do (  
    Echo Procesando el archivo: "%%i" & set fname=%%~ni 
    set FullFilePath=%%i
    set curr_pth=%%~dpi
    ) & call :renombrarArchivos     
goto :eof


:renombrarArchivos 
set  "PTH=%curr_pth%"    
set  "FN=%fname:~0,-1%"
set  "EXE=%BatchFileDir%cambia_nombre.exe"
CALL "%EXE%"  '%PTH%'  "%FN%"  "%EXTENSION%"
goto :eof


:main
call :renombrarArchivos 
::pause
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

llevaba un rato buscando en google y no hay nada de esto en español. Pero en inglés hubo suerte. El código quedaria así:

```
set CurrDir=%cd%
set BatchFileDir=%~dp0

REM UTF-8
chcp 65001

goto :main

:GetFileData
for /R %CurrDir% %%i in (*.*) do (  
    Echo Procesando el archivo: "%%i" & set fname=%%~ni 
    set FullFilePath=%%i
    set curr_pth=%%~dpi
    set EXTENSION=%%~xi
    ) & call :renombrarArchivos     
goto :eof


:renombrarArchivos 
set  "PTH=%curr_pth%"    
set  "FN=%fname:~0,-1%"
set  "EXE=%BatchFileDir%cambia_nombre.exe"
CALL "%EXE%"  '%PTH%'  "%FN%"  "%EXTENSION%"
goto :eof


:main
call :renombrarArchivos 
::pause
goto :eof
```

La respuesta  la encontré en esta fuente:
https://superuser.com/questions/615639/how-do-i-get-only-the-extension-of-a-file-when-writing-a-shell-command-for-a-con